# Find the value of: $\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y)$ given a density function.

Tags: probability

I want to know $\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y)$.

I was given:
$$
f_{x,y}(x,y) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        9xy^2−6x^3y^2−6xy^5+12x^3y^5 & 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1 \\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

I found that:
$$
f_x(x) = \int_{0}^{1} f_x(x,y) dy = 2x
$$

So my initial thought was to do the following:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f_x(x) dx dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} 2x dx dy = \int_{0}^{1} y^2 dy = \frac{1}{3}
$$

However the solution of this question says the following:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f_{x,y}(x,y) dx dy = \int_{0}^{1} 9y^4/2 -6y^6/4 - 6y^7/2 + 12y^9/4 dy = 0.6104
$$

I was wondering why my approach is wrong, and especially why the other approach is right.

Thanks for your help!

V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<Y) ~&=~ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)\,\mathsf P(X<y\mid Y=y) \operatorname d x \tag 1\\ &=~\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y) \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) \operatorname d x \operatorname d y \tag 2 \\ &=~\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y \tag 3 \\ &=~\int_0^1\int_0^y \big(9xy^2−6x^3y^2−6xy^5+12x^3y^5\big)\operatorname d x \operatorname d y \tag 4 \end{align}$$